# JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<Object>(string) doesnt return anything

Tags: c#, .net, json, api

I'm working on a application that collects data from a Battlelog API in a JSON format.
This is what the "player" class looks like in JSONL:

```
{
   "player":{
      "id":173521680,
      "game":"bf4",
      "plat":"pc",
      "name":"1ApRiL",
      "tag":"",
      "dateCheck":1386842250248,
      "dateUpdate":1386827475171,
      "dateCreate":1383962204725,
      "lastDay":"20131206",
      "country":"DE",
      "countryName":"Germany",
      "rank":{
         "nr":9,
         "imgLarge":"bf4/ranks/r9.png",
         "img":"r9",
         "name":"Lance Corporal IV",
         "needed":140000,
         "next":{
            "nr":10,
            "img":"r10",
            "name":"Lance Corporal V",
            "needed":168000,
            "curr":165309,
            "relNeeded":28000,
            "relCurr":25309,
            "relProg":90.38928571428572
         }
      },
      "score":165309,
      "timePlayed":25740,
      "uId":"2832660339132815718",
      "uName":"1ApRiL",
      "uGava":"7222ff803a0a67404aa082b22ff3fa5b",
      "udCreate":1319474914000,
      "blPlayer":"http://battlelog.battlefield.com/bf4/soldier/1ApRiL/stats/173521680/pc/",
      "blUser":"http://battlelog.battlefield.com/bf4/user/1ApRiL/",
      "editable":false,
      "viewable":true,
      "adminable":false,
      "linked":false
   }
}
```

This is what my C# class `Player` looks like:

```
public class Player
{
    public int id { get; set; }
    public string game { get; set; }
    public string plat { get; set; }
    public string name { get; set; }
    public string tag { get; set; }
    public long dateCheck { get; set; }
    public long dateUpdate { get; set; }
    public long dateCreate { get; set; }
    public string lastDay { get; set; }
    public string country { get; set; }
    public object countryName { get; set; }
    public Rank rank { get; set; }
    public int score { get; set; }
    public int timePlayed { get; set; }
    public string uId { get; set; }
    public string uName { get; set; }
    public string uGava { get; set; }
    public long udCreate { get; set; }
    public string blPlayer { get; set; }
    public string blUser { get; set; }
    public bool editable { get; set; }
    public bool viewable { get; set; }
    public bool adminable { get; set; }
    public bool linked { get; set; }
}
```

And finally: this is how I try to deserialize it (data being the JSON data):

```
Player p = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<Player>(data);
```

However when I try to run the method it just doesn't return anything, it leaves all the fields blank, even though I get no exceptions or errors whatsoever.

I'm hoping it's something small and simple that I missed, but I just can't figure out what.

Thanks in advance :)

Comment: Is that the exact JSON you get from the request? Because it was missing a closing `}`. I don't think that's the problem, but it's something to check, at least.

Comment: @Chris Mantle He said that it's just a paste mistake, and that's the reason I deleted my answer as well :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use [this site](http://json2csharp.com/) to get the correct class definitions

```
var root  = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<RootObject>(data);
```

---

```
public class Next
{
    public int nr { get; set; }
    public string img { get; set; }
    public string name { get; set; }
    public int needed { get; set; }
    public int curr { get; set; }
    public int relNeeded { get; set; }
    public int relCurr { get; set; }
    public double relProg { get; set; }
}

public class Rank
{
    public int nr { get; set; }
    public string imgLarge { get; set; }
    public string img { get; set; }
    public string name { get; set; }
    public int needed { get; set; }
    public Next next { get; set; }
}

public class Player
{
    public int id { get; set; }
    public string game { get; set; }
    public string plat { get; set; }
    public string name { get; set; }
    public string tag { get; set; }
    public long dateCheck { get; set; }
    public long dateUpdate { get; set; }
    public long dateCreate { get; set; }
    public string lastDay { get; set; }
    public string country { get; set; }
    public string countryName { get; set; }
    public Rank rank { get; set; }
    public int score { get; set; }
    public int timePlayed { get; set; }
    public string uId { get; set; }
    public string uName { get; set; }
    public string uGava { get; set; }
    public long udCreate { get; set; }
    public string blPlayer { get; set; }
    public string blUser { get; set; }
    public bool editable { get; set; }
    public bool viewable { get; set; }
    public bool adminable { get; set; }
    public bool linked { get; set; }
}

public class RootObject
{
    public Player player { get; set; }
}
```

Comment: That's exactly the website i used to create the class definitions before, so i don't think that could be it.

Comment: @user2722107 you deserialize to `Player` object. See the answer, I used `RootObject`

Comment: Sorry, i missed that, it worked!! Thank you very much!